# I am not able to get my javascript dynamic dropdown code to work in IE 11, but it works in Chrome, FireFox and Edge

Tags: javascript, arraylist

I have two dropdowns, one has the year and the other a list of reports.  For year 2018, I only want to list 3 reports, but for all the other years, I want to list 4 reports.  We dropped this report for 2018.  I can get the code below to work in Chrome, Firefox and Edge, but not in IE 11.  Please help!

I have tried switching to onclick, but that doesn't work either.

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
           var reportCategory = {
    18: ["Counts of Students and Disciplinary Actions by Disciplinary Action Groups", "Counts of DAEP and JJAEP Placement Reason Types", "Counts of Students and Incidents by Discipline Action Reasons"],
    17: ["Counts of Students and Disciplinary Actions by Disciplinary Action Groups", "Counts of DAEP and JJAEP Placement Reason Types", "Counts of Students and Incidents by Discipline Action Reasons", "Counts of Students and Actions by Discipline Action Groups and Discipline Action Reasons"],
    16: ["Counts of Students and Disciplinary Actions by Disciplinary Action Groups", "Counts of DAEP and JJAEP Placement Reason Types", "Counts of Students and Incidents by Discipline Action Reasons", "Counts of Students and Actions by Discipline Action Groups and Discipline Action Reasons"],
    15: ["Counts of Students and Disciplinary Actions by Disciplinary Action Groups", "Counts of DAEP and JJAEP Placement Reason Types", "Counts of Students and Incidents by Discipline Action Reasons", "Counts of Students and Actions by Discipline Action Groups and Discipline Action Reasons"],
    14: ["Counts of Students and Disciplinary Actions by Disciplinary Action Groups", "Counts of DAEP and JJAEP Placement Reason Types", "Counts of Students and Incidents by Discipline Action Reasons", "Counts of Students and Actions by Discipline Action Groups and Discipline Action Reasons"],
    13: ["Counts of Students and Disciplinary Actions by Disciplinary Action Groups", "Counts of DAEP and JJAEP Placement Reason Types", "Counts of Students and Incidents by Discipline Action Reasons", "Counts of Students and Actions by Discipline Action Groups and Discipline Action Reasons"],
    12: ["Counts of Students and Disciplinary Actions by Disciplinary Action Groups", "Counts of DAEP and JJAEP Placement Reason Types", "Counts of Students and Incidents by Discipline Action Reasons", "Counts of Students and Actions by Discipline Action Groups and Discipline Action Reasons"],
    11: ["Counts of Students and Disciplinary Actions by Disciplinary Action Groups", "Counts of DAEP and JJAEP Placement Reason Types", "Counts of Students and Incidents by Discipline Action Reasons", "Counts of Students and Actions by Discipline Action Groups and Discipline Action Reasons"],
    10: ["Counts of Students and Disciplinary Actions by Disciplinary Action Groups", "Counts of DAEP and JJAEP Placement Reason Types", "Counts of Students and Incidents by Discipline Action Reasons", "Counts of Students and Actions by Discipline Action Groups and Discipline Action Reasons"],
    09: ["Counts of Students and Disciplinary Actions by Disciplinary Action Groups", "Counts of DAEP and JJAEP Placement Reason Types", "Counts of Students and Incidents by Discipline Action Reasons", "Counts of Students and Actions by Discipline Action Groups and Discipline Action Reasons"],
    08: ["Counts of Students and Disciplinary Actions by Disciplinary Action Groups", "Counts of DAEP and JJAEP Placement Reason Types", "Counts of Students and Incidents by Discipline Action Reasons", "Counts of Students and Actions by Discipline Action Groups and Discipline Action Reasons"]
}

    function changecat(value) {
        if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("Select_Region_DAG_Summary").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
        else {
            var catOptions = "";
            for (categoryId in reportCategory[value]) {
                catOptions += "<option>" + reportCategory[value][categoryId] + "</option>";
            }
            document.getElementById("Select_Region_DAG_Summary").innerHTML = catOptions;
        }
    }
       </script>
    </head>

<title>Dynamic Drop Down List</title>
    <body>
  <!---School Year --->
        <div class="category_div" id="category_div"> Please specify school year:
   <select  name="school_yr" id="Select_Region_Summary_Year" onchange="changecat(this.value);">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
                        <option value="18">2017-2018 </option>  
                        <option value="17">2016-2017 </option>
                        <option value="16">2015-2016 </option>                      
                        <option value="15">2014-2015 </option>
                        <option value="14">2013-2014 </option>                                              
                        <option value="13">2012-2013 </option>
                        <option value="12">2011-2012 </option>
                        <option value="11">2010-2011 </option>
                        <option value="10">2009-2010 </option>
                        <option value="09">2008-2009 </option>
                        <option value="08">2007-2008 </option>


                     <label for="Select_Region_DAG_Summary">Discipline 
                        Action Group Summary Report <img src="/tea/images/clrpic.gif"
                                  alt="Select a Discipline Action Group Summary Report from the list.">&nbsp; 
                        </label>
                      <select name="Select_Region_DAG_Summary"

                      </select>
                      <select name="Select_Region_DAG_Summary" id="Select_Region_DAG_Summary"style="width: 650px;">
                      <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Discipline Action Group Summary Report from the list</option>


          </select>
```

Comment: Why does your code have 2 of these? `<select name="Select_Region_DAG_Summary">` and only one has an ID property? Your example HTML is malformed in more ways than just this. Your labels and other selects are inside a select element.

Comment: I am new to JavaScript and HTML.  But this works in all other environments, except IE 11.

Comment: I have fixed the HTML:

Comment: <p
        <label for="Select_Region_DAG_Summary">Discipline 
                        Action Group Summary Report <img src="/tea/images/clrpic.gif"
          alt="Select a Discipline Action Group Summary Report from the list.">&nbsp; 
                        </label>
       <select name="Select_Region_DAG_Summary" id="Select_Region_DAG_Summary"style="width: 650px;">
       <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Discipline Action Group Summary Report from the list</option>
       </select>
      </p>